# Chemical numbering

Tags: chemistry, xymtex

The `XyMTeX` package defines the environment `XyMcompd{name}` that results in a counter `\cref{name}` pointing to the compound "name". I would like to know what are the basic steps for this macro `\cref` and how complex it will be to rebuild it without the package `XyMTeX`.

Thanks for your help

Bernhard

Comment: I am not familiar with `XyMTeX` -- it seems to be a very special TeX format. Perhaps you should provide us with a starter document

Comment: On the other hand: `\cref` is a command most likely from `cleveref` package

Comment: @ChristianHupfer XyMTeX is a collection of 27 packages (counting the `sty` files) (and its documentation is 780 pages strong!) for typesetting of all aspects concerning chemistry.

Comment: If you're interested in a package for numbering of chemical compounds have a look at the [`chemnum` package](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/chemnum). I am not familar with XyMTeX's mechanism so it's hard to say how easy it will be to rebuild its `\cref`…

Comment: For comparison, \eqref is defined as (condensed) \newcommand{\eqref}[1]{\textup{\hbox{\m@th\normalfont(\ignorespaces\ref{#1}\unskip\@@italiccorr}}}

Comment: @Clemens: I know of the chemnum package, but as a support for chemnum in latexml is farfetched. I would very much know how large a condensed version of chemnum (only the number), and the macro with the name would be?

Comment: A *very* condensed version would be something like `\newcounter{compound} \newcommand*\defcompound[1]{\refstepcounter{compound}\label{cpd:#1}} \newcommand*\refcompound[1]{\textbf{\ref{cpd:#1}}}`. This defines `\defcompound{bla}` to set a label and `\refcompound{bla}` to reference it.

Comment: @clemens: I've seen that huge documentation too. I don't read such stuff to answer a question

Comment: \documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{book}
\usepackage[ngerman]{babel}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\newcounter{compound}%
\DeclareRobustCommand*{\defcmpd}[1]{\refstepcounter{compound}\label{cpd:#1}}
\DeclareRobustCommand*{\cref}[1]{\textbf{\ref{cpd:#1}}}. 
\begin{document}
\end{document}

ends with error missing begin document???

Comment: Actually in works when the line \DeclarerobustCommand*\cref.... goes to a place after \begin{document} which is strange.

Comment: @BernhardKleine you have a `.` after your `\cref` definition and before `\begin{document}`

Comment: @clemens thank you that was to small for to see :)

Answer (score 4):

You can find the complete compound labeling mechanism of XyMTeX in the file `chemist.sty`:

```
\@ifundefined{chapter}{\newcounter{compd}}{\newcounter{compd}[chapter]}
\def\thecompd{\arabic{compd}}
\def\compd{\leavevmode\refstepcounter{compd}{\large\bf \thecompd}}
\def\nocompd{\refstepcounter{compd}}
\def\compdlabel#1{\compd \label{#1}}
\def\nocompdlabel#1{\nocompd \label{#1}}
\@ifundefined{bf}{\def\bf{\normalfont\bfseries}}{}
\def\cref#1{{\bf \ref{#1}}}
```

---

Let's go through it:

```
\@ifundefined{chapter}{\newcounter{compd}}{\newcounter{compd}[chapter]}
```

This defines a counter `compd` which if a macro `\chapter` exists is added to the counter `chapter`'s reset list.

```
\def\thecompd{\arabic{compd}}
```

This redefines `\thecompd` from `\@arabic \c@compd` to `\arabic{compd}` which is basically redundant.

```
\def\compd{\leavevmode\refstepcounter{compd}{\large\bf \thecompd}}
```

This defines a macro `\compd` which steps said counter and prints the number in bold and large. The environment `XyMcompd` which you mention in your question uses this macro if the corresponding argument is not empty.

```
\def\nocompd{\refstepcounter{compd}}
```

This defines a macro `\nocompd` which steps said counter but doesn't print the number.

```
\def\compdlabel#1{\compd \label{#1}}
```

This defines a macro `\compdlabel` with a mandatory argument which steps the counter, prints the number and adds a label using the argument.

```
\def\nocompdlabel#1{\nocompd \label{#1}}
```

The same but doesn't print the number.

```
\@ifundefined{bf}{\def\bf{\normalfont\bfseries}}{}
```

This checks if `\bf` is undefined and if it is defines it to be `\normalfont\bfseries`.

```
\def\cref#1{{\bf \ref{#1}}}
```

This defines `\cref` to take an argument to refer to a label and prints it in bold.

---

Here is some slightly modified code which copies this:

```
\documentclass{article}

\newcounter{compound}
\newcommand*\compoundformat[1]{\textbf{\large#1}}
\newcommand*\compound{\leavevmode\refstepcounter{compound}\compoundformat{\thecompound}}
\newcommand*\nocompound{\refstepcounter{compound}}
\newcommand*\compoundlabel[1]{\compound\label{#1}}
\newcommand*\nocompoundlabel[1]{\nocompound\label{#1}}
\newcommand*\compoundref[1]{\compoundformat{\ref{#1}}}

\begin{document}

foo \compound\ bar and \compoundlabel{ethanol} and later \compoundref{ethanol}.

\end{document}
```

[image]

As comparison the corresponding code with XyMTeX:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{xymtex}

\begin{document}

foo \compd\ bar and \compdlabel{ethanol} and later \cref{ethanol}.

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: thank you very much for this. I will come back to it. I try to make this latexml compatible as well which seems challenge by its own. However the SVG structure to not show well in latexml and we have to solve that first. Afterwards I have already some code which might work, with an environment so draw the structure and a newfloat to make the labels work.
thanks again

Answer (score 1):

I used the code from XyMTeX, and the structures are labeled, however the references are still missing which I do not understand since they are inside a float which should give the proper reference at least for the `\mevalonate` macro.

@Clemens BTW Using your code and the \compoundlabel and \compoundref pair resulted in the same warnings: `Latex failed to resolve 2 reference(s)`

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{book}
\usepackage[ngerman]{babel}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{graphicx,float,hyperref,calc,caption,mwe}
\newfloat{Mycomp}{hbtp}{cmp}[chapter] % programmed figures
\floatname{Mycomp}{}
\makeatletter\let\ftype@Mycomp\ftype@figure % figure and compound are 
\setlength{\unitlength}{0.1mm}
%taken from chemist.sty from the XyMTex package
\@ifundefined{chapter}{\newcounter{compd}}{\newcounter{compd}[chapter]}
\def\thecompd{\arabic{compd}}
\def\compd{\leavevmode\refstepcounter{compd}{\large\bf \thecompd}}
\def\nocompd{\refstepcounter{compd}}
\def\compdlabel#1{\compd \label{#1}}
\def\nocompdlabel#1{\nocompd \label{#1}}
\@ifundefined{bf}{\def\bf{\normalfont\bfseries}}{}
\def\cref#1{{\bf \ref{#1}}}

\DeclareRobustCommand{\mevalonate}{%
%
\begin{Mycomp}[H]
\fbox{
    \parbox[c]{450\unitlength}{%
    \centering  
    {\large\bfseries Mevalonate}\quad\compdlabel{Mevalonat}\\\vspace*{.5em}

    \includegraphics[width=400\unitlength]{example-image-a}
    }%
}
\end{Mycomp}
}
\DeclareRobustCommand{\mevalonatePP}{%
%
\fbox{
    \parbox[c]{450\unitlength}{%
    \centering  
    {\large\bfseries Mevalonate pyrophosphate}\quad\compdlabel{MevalonatPP}\\\vspace*{.5em}

    \includegraphics[width=400\unitlength]{example-image-b}
}%
}
}
\begin{document}

\mevalonate     \mevalonatePP

In the text you will refer to the structures by \cref{mevalonatePP} and \cref{mevalonate}.

\end{document}
```

Comment: If you change the \compdlabel to mevalonate and mevalonatePP than it works.
Thank you Clemens